# How to configure the Grails embedded Tomcat to use the file based security realm

Tags: grails, embedded-tomcat-7

I need to create a user/password for the embedded Tomcat, since my app uses JAAS. I found [some examples](http://michaelspaulding.blogspot.ca/2011/01/configuring-embedded-tomcat-in-grails.html), but they refer to older versions of Grails. I am using 2.3.5.

The link above advises to create users via events, in a Grails script:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
println "Loading users"

   tomcat.addUser("user", "password")
   tomcat.addRole("user", "group")
}
```

But when I create a Grails script in the `scripts` folder, it is pre-populated with this:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(_Events: "The description of the script goes here!") {
// TODO: Implement script here
}

setDefaultTarget(_Events)
```

How to add the user in the new version of Grails? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the `create-script` script for this, that's to create a standalone callable script, e.g. `grails foo`. Just manually create `scripts/_Events.groovy` and add `eventFoo = ...` event callbacks. This isn't a complete answer though because with forking in 2.3 you need to configure Tomcat differently

Comment: @burt-beckwith thanks, I guess I am back to the documentation then. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the event in the file `scripts/_Events.groovy`. If it's not there, just create it. If it's there, just append your event to the existing content.

Make sure to execute `stop-app` and `run-app` so that the event is processed. When executing `run-app`, you should see the output of your `println`-statement.